# Trouble with Python Text Game

Tags: python

So, this may, or may not get complicated. Hopefully not.
In any case, I've been writing an fairly ambitious Python text game in my spare time, just to see if I can get it done. I realize there's tons of interactive fiction engines, parsers, etc out there, but Im doing it from scratch. Its the way I learn - the hard way, I guess.

So here's how it breaks down:

- You have the main() function in the engine.py module which pretty much does grabs a room-object & displays the room description. Then it waits for user input and sends it to the parser.
- The parser in the parser.py module runs through the user input and constructs a Sentence object (made up of a verb & the object - which can be a noun or direction). The Sentence object also has a output function which calls the xxxCommand class from inside the command.py module.
- Example: You input "go north" & the parser accepts it as a suitable sentence. So the parser output function will search for the GoCommand class.

Now here's where I'm having trouble. Before I continue and for the sake of clarity, I'll paste my Engine & Sentence class:

```
class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, start_room):
        self.L = lexi.Lexicon() #Imported earlier
        self.P = parser.Parser() #Imported earlier
        self.room = start_room

    def main(self):
        while True:
            self.room.describe() #Describes the current room.

            # Ask for user prompt
            input = raw_input(self.room.prompt)
            cmd = input.lower()

            # Scans user input & creates tokens from Lexicon table
            # For example: [('verb', 'go'), ('direction', 'north')]
            tokenizer = self.L.scan(cmd)

            # Runs through tokens and creates a sentence object
            # With noun & object attributes
            parsed_sentence = self.P.parse_sentence(tokenizer)

            # See below
            parsed_sentence.output(self.room)


class Sentence(object):

    def __init__(self, verb, noun):
        self.verb = verb[1]
        self.obj = noun[1]

    # There's a command module with different xxxCommand classes with an execute method
    # as seen on last line. So pretend the command module has already been imported.
    def output(self, current_room):
        verb = self.verb.capitalize()
        obj = self.obj
        command = getattr(commands, '%sCommand' % verb)(obj)
        command.execute(current_room)
```

Ok, after that long winded setup, I have my GoCommand class like so:

```
# Subclassed from Command parent class. Has one method called execute. Does nothing else.
class GoCommand(Command):
    def __init__(self, direction):
        self.direction = direction

    def execute(self, current_room):
        # 'E' is the instantiation of the Engine class, declared within engine.py
        from engine import E

        # self.direction is 'north' in our example
        # current_room.map is a dict within any Room class named 'map'.
        # For example: Intro.map = {'north': char_intro }
        if self.direction in current_room.map:
            print "You head %s\n" % self.direction # Pretty explanatory

            # HERE'S WHERE I HAVE TROUBLE
            E.room = current_room.map[self.direction]
        else:
            print "You can't go that way."
```

So what I was hoping to achieve was that when the loop finishes, E.room would equal a room class called char_intro and as the loop runs through again, it displays char_intro's description, essentially starting over again.

This is not whats happening. It just stays in the first room. Although the GoCommand.execute() is being run, E.room doesnt change. Anyone know why?

Oh dear god, I realize this is long but I hope someone knows what im talking about & can help me out. How should I fix this so that when the user says go north & there is a path set for North, it changes the room class??

Comment: I don't immediately see anything that wouldn't work, but one guess of something it could be is that perhaps you have more than one `Engine` and don't realize it?

Comment: you mean in my python path?

Comment: No, I mean perhaps you have an `E` as a part of the `engine` module and another `E` as a local variable and they're different, maybe?

Comment: self.direction is not in current_room.map?

Comment: As of the E variable... I double checked that. Its the only one.
And self.direction is _supposed to be_ an argument passed from the Sentence object (which can be a noun or direction).

I wonder if it has to do with the loop itself, some how...?

Comment: suppositions are bad. test them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the loop in Engine.main() works just as its supposed to, but I took self.room.describe() out of the while statement:

```
def main(self):
    self.room.describe() #Describes the current room.
    while True:
        # Ask for user prompt
        input = raw_input(self.room.prompt)
        cmd = input.lower()
        ...etc, etc, etc...
```

Then I changed the GoCommand to:

```
class GoCommand(Command):
def __init__(self, direction):
    self.direction = direction

def execute(self):
    # 'E' is the instantiation of the Engine class, declared within engine.py
    from engine import E

    # self.direction is 'north' in our example
    if self.direction in E.room.map.keys():
        print "You head %s\n" % self.direction # Pretty explanatory

        E.room = E.room.map[self.direction]
        print E.room.describe()
    else:
        print "You can't go that way."
```

And everything works as its supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the game state (current room, inventory) is being kept on the Engine. Just for comparison's sake, look over the text adventure game I wrote as a command-parsing exercise at http://www.ptmcg.com/geo/python/confs/adventureEngine.py.txt. In that code, I kept the current room and inventory on a Player instance. The main game loop then looks like:

```
parser = Parser()
p = Player("Joe")
p.moveTo( startRoom )
while not p.gameOver:
    cmdstr = raw_input(">> ")
    cmd = parser.parseCmd(cmdstr)
    if cmd is not None:
        cmd.command( p )
```

`parseCmd` parses the input string, and if valid, returns a Command object that implements `command(p)` where p is the Player. Through the player, the command has access to the current room, current inventory, and any special player state or skills (for instance, a player with heightened vision might have better odds at detecting a trap when entering a particular room). This also makes it easier to test your commands with a mock Player, instead of having to mock any globals or attributes in the Engine itself.

Comment: You dont have this on github or anything, do you?

Comment: No, it's just the one file.